# Test Scenario to check if the seat is available or not on Redbus.in Booking system

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Site: [www.redbus.in](http://www.redbus.in/):

1. Enter from, To, Date and click on Search Buses
2. Click on view seat below fare.
3. A new popup window appears where user can select the seat of their choice.
4. Here the seats which are already reserved will be disabled.
5. I want to capture the seats which are available for booking in excel or data table.

Please guide me from step 3 I will write the code for step 1, 2.

Comment: Have you identified the popup window and its controls in your Object Repository?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to one particular site, and you have not demonstrated even a minimal understanding of the problem. As it stands it's therefore a "do my job/homework for me" request rather than a useful question.

Comment: @Admdrew: I have completed step 1 and step 2 I am stuck on stuck on step 3 as I am not getting idea how do I make QTP understand that which seats are enabled and how do I write test script to show the seats which are available for booking. Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

Comment: @Xiaofu: I am trying to automate similar test scenario as I cannot share the AUT link I have found redbus.in matches my requirement I will write test script for rest of the scenario's I just need experts guidance to know how can I automate this scenario. If you want more details I will share it with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to check which property is different in 'Available seat' objects and 'Occupied Seat' objects in that pop-up window. In given redbus site, ‘class’ property differentiates them with value 'availableSeat' for not booked seats.

Here below is code for step 3 to 5:

```
'seats are of object type link, hence creating description object for collection link child objects

Set oDesc = Description.Create()
oDesc("micclass").Value = "Link"

'Here Seatmap is pop-up window which has collection of seats link

Set seatlinks = Browser("Online Bus Booking: Book").Page("Book Ticket - Search Buses").WebElement("Seatmap").ChildObjects(oDesc)

For i = 0 To seatlinks.count - 1  Step 1 
 DataTable.SetCurrentRow(i+1)

If seatlinks(i).GetROProperty("class") = "availableSeat" Then

    DataTable.Value("AvailableSeats","Global") = seatlinks(i).GetROProperty("innertext") & " -Seat Available"

Else

DataTable.Value("AvailableSeats","Global") = seatlinks(i).GetROProperty("innertext") & " -Seat Occupied"
End If

Next
```

So it will give list of 'Available' and 'Occupied' seats with seat number in your global datatable.

Answer (score -1):

So you want help with only 3rd step.. I guess there is no property or method which can check if the object is enabled or disabled. Please correct me if I am wrong.
Your question makes sense as this scenarios can be encountered in any project.

Comment: This is not an answer and is better suited as a comment. I know you don't yet have the rep for that and i normally would add a comment for you, but the OP basically answered in her most recent comment.